# Quiero obtener los datos correctamente del segundo toque en dispositivo tactil (event.touches[1])

Tags: javascript, css, touch

El problema es el siguiente...
el codigo a continuacion se trata de 3 elementos a los que se le puede hacer toques y obtener las coordenadas mediante:

```
ee.touches[0]; y ee.touches[1];
```

Cuando activo el primer touch en el div "botondisparoContenedor" e intento hacer el segundo en "botonleftContenedor" este no funciona por que es como si la pantalla se corriera unos cuantos PX a la derecha pero si intento hacer el segundo touch en "botonrightContenedor" este hace la funcion del "botonleftContenedor" por ese mismo motivo.

quizas sea una tonteria pero no hayo la solcion. Recien aprendiendo
Javascript asi que comprendan mis novatadas jejeje

```
<style>
.botonleftContenedor{
    width:19vw;
    height:100vh;
    float:left;
    background-color: #00000090
}
.botonrightContenedor{
    width:19vw;
    height:100vh;
    float:left;
    background-color: #00000090
}
.botondisparoContenedor{
    width:19vw;
    height:100vh;
    float:right;
    background-color: #00000090
}
.inicio{
    width:90vw;
    height:10vh;
}
</style>

<div id="botonleftContenedor" class="botonleftContenedor"></div>
<div id="botonrightContenedor" class="botonrightContenedor"></div>
<div id="botondisparoContenedor" class="botondisparoContenedor"></div>
<div id="inicio" class="inicio"></div>


<script>
//MOVIMIENTO DEL JUGADOR
let actDireccion = 0; //0 Quieto / 1 Derecha / 2 Izquierda
let iniciarMovimiento;
var direccionActual;
var tomaEstaDireccion;
var disparo = 0;
var activadoDisp = 0;

var clickMoverRight = 
document.getElementById('botonrightContenedor');
var clickMoverLeft = 
document.getElementById('botonleftContenedor');
var clickdisparar = 
document.getElementById("botondisparoContenedor");

function accionDireccion(ee) {


if((ee.type === "keydown")||(ee.type === "touchstart")||(ee.type === "mousedown")||(ee.type === "pointerdown")||(ee.type === "touchmove")){


    if(ee.type !== "keydown"){
        var touch = ee.touches[0];
        var posX = touch.clientX;
        var posY = touch.clientY;
        direccionActual = document.elementFromPoint(posX, posY);    
        if(direccionActual.id){     tomaEstaDireccion = direccionActual.id;     }
    }



    if(ee.type !== "keydown"){
        if((tomaEstaDireccion != "botonrightContenedor")&&(tomaEstaDireccion != "botonleftContenedor")){
            touch = ee.touches[1];
            //touch = ee.changedTouches[1];
            posX = touch.clientX;
            posY = touch.clientY;
            direccionActual = document.elementFromPoint(posX, posY);    
            if(direccionActual.id){     tomaEstaDireccion = direccionActual.id;     }
        }
    }

document.getElementById("inicio").innerHTML = parseInt(posX) + ' -- ' + parseInt(posY);

 console.log(ee.changedTouches[0]);     

    
    if (((ee.keyCode === 39)||(tomaEstaDireccion === "botonrightContenedor"))&&((actDireccion === 0)||(actDireccion === 2))) {
        actDireccion = 1;
    }else if(((ee.keyCode === 37)||(tomaEstaDireccion === "botonleftContenedor"))&&((actDireccion === 0)||(actDireccion === 1))){
        actDireccion = 2;
    }

}else if((ee.type === "keyup")||(ee.type === "touchend")||(ee.type === "mouseup")||(ee.type === "pointerup")){
    
    
    if (((ee.keyCode === 39)||(tomaEstaDireccion === "botonrightContenedor"))&&(actDireccion === 1)){
        actDireccion = 0;
    }else if(((ee.keyCode === 37)||(tomaEstaDireccion === "botonleftContenedor"))&&(actDireccion === 2)){
        actDireccion = 0;
    }
}
}









function dispararAhoraa(event) {

console.log(event.type);
if(((event.keyCode === 32)||(event.type === "keydown")||(event.type === "touchstart")||(event.type === "mousedown")||(event.type === "pointerdown"))&&(activadoDisp === 0)){

        
        if((event.keyCode === 32)||(event.target.id === "botondisparoContenedor")){
        disparo++;

        iniciarDisparos = setInterval(function() {
            disparo++;      
        }, 20);
        activadoDisp = 1;

        }
}

}


function dejaDeDisparar(evente){
if((evente.keyCode === 32)||(evente.type === "keyup")||(evente.type === "touchend")||(evente.type === "mouseup")||(evente.type === "pointerup")){
    activadoDisp = 0;
}   
}



clickdisparar.addEventListener("touchend", dejaDeDisparar);
clickdisparar.addEventListener("touchstart", dispararAhoraa);

clickMoverRight.addEventListener("touchmove", accionDireccion);
clickMoverRight.addEventListener("touchstart", accionDireccion);
clickMoverRight.addEventListener("touchend", accionDireccion);

clickMoverLeft.addEventListener("touchmove", accionDireccion);
clickMoverLeft.addEventListener("touchstart", accionDireccion);
clickMoverLeft.addEventListener("touchend", accionDireccion);




document.addEventListener("keydown", accionDireccion);
document.addEventListener("keyup", accionDireccion);
document.addEventListener("keydown", dispararAhoraa);
document.addEventListener("keyup", dejaDeDisparar);

</script>
```